# Unable to send email via localhost

Tags: c#, iis-7

I am getting the following error:

```
 Failure sending mail
```

and inner exception is

```
 Unable to connect to the remote server
```

in C#

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("you@yourcompany.com", "user@hotmail.com","Newsletter", "This is a test mail");
 SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
 client.Send(mail);
```

This is my local smtp email setting in IIS 7.

[image]

Also installed the smtp server tools

[image]

Comment: is the smtp service actually running?

Comment: I dont see anything in services. Where do i start the smtp service?

Comment: probably in the iis manager somewhere.

Comment: Installed the smtp server tools feature. Still getting the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "Email Address" field in the IIS SMTP settings to the FROM address you are using.

[**SOURCE**](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7-and-above)